# Stringifying an Inline::Python::Object-encoded Unicode string

Tags: python, perl, unicode

[Inline::Python](http://search.cpan.org/~nine/Inline-Python-0.43/Python.pod)::Object overloads `'""'` (stringify) with this:

```
sub __inline_str__ {
    my ($self) = @_;
    return Inline::Python::py_has_attr($self, '__str__') ? $self->__str__() : $self;
}
```

The [`__str__()`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__) method attempts a conversion to ASCII, meaning that if an `Inline::Python::Object` object represents a Python Unicode string, the likely outcome is:

> exceptions.UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\xe7' in position 6: ordinal not in range(128) at line 1252

One workaround that seems to be working, is replacing `$self->__str__()` with `$self->encode('utf8')`. I don't much like modifying a module like this, and subclassing it seems like a considerable challenge.  Moreover, I'm not 100% sure why my fix even works, which is slightly worrying.

I'm quite sure I'm not the first person ever that needs to use a Python Unicode string in Perl. How is this supposed to be done?

Comment: The **normal** behaviour would be for your Python code to explicitly encode; don't use `str(unicodevalue)` where `unicodevalue.encode('utf8')` can be used.

Comment: That would make sense, but unfortunately "my" Python code is not really mine, I'm using `Inline::Python` to load the HTTP4Store Python library into Perl. Having to modify a Python library would be as irritating as having to modify `Inline::Python`, only more risky since I'm not that proficient in Python. :-(

Comment: I'll admit to not knowing what Perl would be calling the `__inline_str__` sub *for*; if the Python source code is decoded to Unicode, then parsed, then that's where this went wrong as byte string literals in Python hold plain unencoded bytes (so values 0-255). Do you know what codec Perl used to decode the source code in the first place?

Comment: I don't *think* Perl actually touches the Python sources besides what is included in my Perl source, which is simply `from HTTP4Store import HTTP4Store as HTTP4Store_Python`. To be honest though, I'm really not sure how `Inline::Python` works and I'm also not good enough in XS to be able to tell from the source...

Comment: That doesn't actually use string literals; from the documentation I understood that the module just creates a child process to run Python, so it's a little puzzling why it tries to parse a string literal anywhere.

Comment: If this function is called on any Python object then you can't use `.encode()` (it is not defined for arbitrary object). If the string representation is used for debugging then you could call `repr(self)` (via `py_call_function`) instead of `self.__str__()`.

Comment: `.encode()` would be called only when the `Inline::Python::Object` object has some attribute named `__str__`. I'm not sure what that means, since `py_has_att` is not documented and I am unable to understand the XS code, but I would expect it means that the object represents a string of some sort. `repr` sounds like a good idea (at least it would change a Python or Inline problem into a Perl problem), but it still has the drawback that the module code must be changed.

Comment: @scozy: `__str__` special method is defined for `object` type in Python (the root type) so many objects in Python have it by default (and all objects in Python 3 unless it is explicitely removed). Only instances of old style classes that do not define themselves `__str__` won't have it. The presence of `__str__` doesn't mean anything.

Comment: Did you alreay play with `-C` parameter? see `man perlrun`!

Comment: @F.Hauri, I'm using `use open qw( :std :utf8 )` in all my files. Do you think using `-C` might give a different result?

Comment: Theoricaly no... I think! But because of the particular case of *Inline::Python::Object*, maybe trying `-CD` or `-CDS` won't help, but will not be too hard to test ;-)

Comment: I took a while to get back to it, but I did try `-CDS`, without success. :-/

Answer (score -1):

> One workaround that seems to be working, is replacing $self->**str**()
>   with $self->encode('utf8').

This is the correct way to handle this. That code will encode any UTF characters as something like this:

```
>>> u'\ufdef'.__str__()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
UnicodeEncodeError: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\ufdef' in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
>>> u'\ufdef'.encode('utf-8')
'\xef\xb7\xaf'
```

You will then probably want to use a UTF-8 decoder in your PERL to correctly display the value.

Comment: That will be robust if you can prove that `py_has_attr($self, '__str__')` will never return a true value for an object that has no `encode` method. Even in that case, though, it doesn't really answer my question which was about how to use Inline::Python, not how to _change_ it.